# Comparing performance of generated queries for Any() vs Count() in Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, performance, t-sql, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

In my project I use Entity Framework 4.4.0.0 and I have the following dilemma. I have to check if an user is activated. My query looks like:

Any()

```
_context.Users.Any(u => u.Id == userId && u.IsActivated);
```

The generated sql is:

```sql
SELECT CASE
         WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1]
                        FROM   [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
                        WHERE  ( [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0 )
                               AND ( [Extent1].[IsActivated] = 1 )) ) THEN cast(1 AS BIT)
         WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1]
                            FROM   [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent2]
                            WHERE  ( [Extent2].[Id] = @p__linq__0 )
                                AND ( [Extent2].[IsActivated] = 1 )) ) THEN cast(0 AS BIT)
       END AS [C1]
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS X) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

For `Count()` I get this query:

```sql
SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM   [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE  ( [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0 )
               AND ( [Extent1].[IsActivated] = 1 )) AS [GroupBy1]
```

Does this looks right? I am not very good as sql ... but it looks not very efficient to me. Am I missing something?

Is '`select count(*) from dbo.Users where id=@id and IsActivated=1`' less efficient?

Comment: The first one looks inefficient, but remember that an `EXISTS` will stop as soon as a matching record is found.  The only problem I have with it is the repeat of the query in the second `WHEN`.  I would have expected it to use `ELSE cast(0 as bit)`.  However, the query optimizer should only execute that query once.

Comment: @cadrell0 - The optimiser won't only execute it once. See [Unnecessarily bad performance for coalesce(subquery)](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/336002/unnecessarily-bad-performance-for-coalesce-subquery)

Comment: @MartinSmith isn't that the point of the optimizer?

Comment: @cadrell0 - SQL Server currently has no logic to detect these repeated sub queries. Maybe at some point the Microsoft Research paper mentioned in the above linked Connect Item will make its way into the product.

Comment: Unless you need to know what SQL is actually running, I wouldn't question  `Does this look right?`.  It's will get optimized by the SQL Compiler most likely to into query you mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends.

The `EXISTS` implementation isn't that great either. It will perform the check twice if there are `0` rows. In that case the `COUNT` one will be better as it only has to search for the non existent row and count it once.

You may find that checking

```
_context.Users
        .Where(u => u.Id == userId && u.IsActivated)
        .Select(u=> true)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

gives a better plan than both (amended following Luke's suggestion). Testing on EF4 the query generated is along the lines of

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) cast(1 AS BIT) AS [C1]
FROM   Users
WHERE  userId = @userId
       AND IsActivated = 1
```

Meaning it doesn't process unnecessary additional rows if more than one exists and only performs the search for rows matching the `WHERE` once.

Comment: I agree this will be faster based on what you have said about exists, is the select in there to avoid downloading the whole row? how about `.Select(u=> true).FirstOrDefault()` (default of bool is false eg no rows => false)

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - Yes I agree that's better. Doesn't rely on selecting a not nullable column and nicer to get the boolean back directly without having to do the `== null` check anyway. The query generated is `SELECT TOP (1) cast(1 as bit) AS [C1] FROM .... WHERE`

Comment: Also, i had a bit of a look at the EF source around any and i think its the way it is so that it can be used in a sub query inside of a larger expression, I'm not too sure what a better way to write this is than exists if its in the middle of a larger DB query. (http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlGen/SqlGenerator.cs search for 'result.Append("EXISTS (");')

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.
When you perform a count you will select all the entries that match your clause and count then. Using Any() your query will return at a first sign of a registry that match the clause. 
I'm my opnion it's always better to use Any() than count(), except when you really need that number